# can't load OcMockito

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mocking, xctestcase

my problem is when I launch the test with OCMockito Xcode inform me that `xctest[3096:115464] The bundle “Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.`
and also `Library not loaded: @rpath/OCMockito.framework/Versions/A/OCMockito`

when I check the path of  the OCMockito framework in the search path build setting of the test target, every thing look correct!!!
this my search path settings screen
[image]
and this is the OCMockito in the files[image] finder

PS: I used the mockito framework to make tests to static library

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem the error is that I Used OcMokito instead of OCMockitoIOS :)